# Find element in boost multi_index_container

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, hash, boost-multi-index

In my code I need to have a functionality to iterate over all elements and check if there some element already exists possibly as soon as possible, so my choice fell on boost multi index container where I can use vector and unordered_set interface for my class Animal at the same time. The problem is that I am not able to find some element through unordered_set interface since I replaced key from std::string to std::array<char, 50> and adjusted the code, and I don't know what I am doing wrong ?

code:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/dnCaEzYVdXkTFBGo

```
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <memory>

#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/ordered_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/composite_key.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/sequenced_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/identity.hpp>

int constexpr elements_size{ 1'000'000 };

struct Animal
{
Animal(std::string name, std::string description, int leg, int age, double maxSpeed) noexcept :
    description_{std::move(description)}, leg_{leg}, age_{age}, maxSpeed_{maxSpeed}
{
    std::copy(name.begin(), name.end(), name_.data());
}

Animal(std::string const& name, std::string const& description) noexcept :
    description_{description}
{
    std::copy(name.begin(), name.end(), name_.data());
}

Animal(Animal&& animal) noexcept
{
    name_ = name_;
    description_ = std::move(animal).description_;
    leg_ = animal.leg_;
    age_ = animal.age_;
    maxSpeed_ = animal.maxSpeed_;
}

Animal(Animal const& animal) noexcept
{
    name_ = animal.name_;
    description_ = animal.description_;
    leg_ = animal.leg_;
    age_ = animal.age_;
    maxSpeed_ = animal.maxSpeed_;
}

Animal& operator=(Animal&& animal) noexcept
{
    name_ = name_;
    description_ = std::move(animal).description_;
    leg_ = animal.leg_;
    age_ = animal.age_;
    maxSpeed_ = animal.maxSpeed_;
    return *this;
}

Animal& operator=(Animal const& animal) noexcept
{
    name_ = animal.name_;
    description_ = animal.description_;
    leg_ = animal.leg_;
    age_ = animal.age_;
    maxSpeed_ = animal.maxSpeed_;
    return *this;
}

std::array<char, 50> name_;
std::string description_;
int leg_{0};
int age_{0};
double maxSpeed_{0.0};
};

struct Hasher
{
bool print_;
Hasher(bool print = false): print_{print} {}
std::size_t operator()(std::array<char, 50> const& name) const
{
    if (print_)
        std::cout << "array hash" << std::hash<std::string_view>{}(name.data()) << std::endl;
    return std::hash<std::string_view>{}(name.data());
}
std::size_t operator()(std::string const& name) const
{
    if (print_)
        std::cout << "string hash" << std::hash<std::string_view>{}(name.c_str()) << std::endl;
    return std::hash<std::string_view>{}(name.c_str());
}
std::size_t operator()(const char* name) const
{
    if (print_)
        std::cout << "char hash" << std::hash<std::string_view>{}(name) << std::endl;
    return std::hash<std::string_view>{}(name);
}
};

struct KeysComparator
{
bool operator()(std::array<char, 50> const& a1, std::array<char, 50> const& a2) const {return a1 == a2; }
template <typename T>
bool operator()(std::string const& n1, T const& t) const
{
    std::cout << "### value.name_" << t.value.name_.data() << ", n1: " << n1 << std::endl;
    return n1 == t.value.name_.data();
}
};

template<typename TimePoint>
std::string getElapsedTime(TimePoint const& start, TimePoint const& end)
{
auto micro = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end - start);
auto milli = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(micro);
auto sec = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(milli);

return {std::to_string(micro.count()) + " µs, " + std::to_string(milli.count()) + " ms, " + std::to_string(sec.count()) + " s"};
}

template<typename TimePoint>
void printStatistics(TimePoint const& emplace_start, TimePoint const& emplace_end, TimePoint const& iterate_start, TimePoint const& iterate_end,
TimePoint const& find_start, TimePoint const& find_end, intmax_t const sum, std::string target)
{
std::cout << "Elapsed time emplace: "  << getElapsedTime(emplace_start, emplace_end)
    << "  |  iterate: " << getElapsedTime(iterate_start, iterate_end)
    << "  |  find: " << getElapsedTime(find_start, find_end)
    << ", sum:" << sum << " , calculation for " << target << std::endl;
}

void test()
{
using namespace boost::multi_index;
using Animal_multi = multi_index_container<Animal, indexed_by<
    random_access<>,
    hashed_unique<
        composite_key<Animal, member<Animal, std::array<char, 50>, &Animal::name_>>,
        composite_key_hash<Hasher>,
        composite_key_equal_to<KeysComparator>>
>>;

Animal_multi container;
auto emplace_start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
for (auto i = 0; i < elements_size; ++i)
    container.emplace_back("the really long name of some animal 12345678910_" + std::to_string(i),
                           "bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla", 4, i, i + 2);
auto emplace_end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

intmax_t sum{0};
auto iterate_start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
for (auto const& e : container)
    sum += e.age_;
auto iterate_end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

KeysComparator key_comparator;
Hasher hasher{true};
auto find_start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
auto &container_interface = container.get<1>();
auto isSucceeded = container_interface.count("the really long name of some animal 12345678910_" + std::to_string(elements_size-1),
                                             hasher, key_comparator);
if (not isSucceeded)
    std::cout << "WARN: Element has not been found." << std::endl;
auto find_end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

printStatistics(emplace_start, emplace_end, iterate_start, iterate_end, find_start, find_end, sum, "Animal_multi (boost multi_index)");
}

int main()
{
    test();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shortest hint, use `project` to translate iterators across indexes. I'll read your question later

Comment: Okay, it wasn't _that_. Posted an answer instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of bugs like in the move constructor:

```
name_ = name_; // oops this does nothing at all
```

Just follow [Rule Of Zero](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/rule-of-zero.html). This will also inform you that `std::string` copy/assignment are *not* `noexcept`.

The name copy should probably be length-limited:

```
std::copy_n(name.begin(), std::min(name.size(), name_.size()), name_.data());
```

At this point I notice something that might explain your trouble: you don't NUL-terminate, nor make sure that the array is 0-initialized.

### BINGO

Indeed, just a few lines down I spot:

```
return std::hash<std::string_view>{}(name.data());
```

That's... UB! Your string_view might contain indeterminate data, but what's worse, you would NEVER have copied the terminating NUL character. So, `std::string_view` will model a string with indeterminate length which WILL likely exceed 50.

> Read here about [Nasal Demons (UB)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)
>
> Such are the perils of skipping standard library types for the old C craft.

### First Dig

So, here's the entirety of the class with equal/better characteristics:

```
using Name = std::array<char, 50>;

struct Animal {
    Animal(std::string_view name, std::string description,
           int leg = 0, int age = 0, double maxSpeed = 0) noexcept 
        : name_{0}, // zero initialize!
          description_{std::move(description)},
          leg_{leg},
          age_{age},
          maxSpeed_{maxSpeed}
    {
        constexpr auto Capacity = std::tuple_size<Name>::value;
        constexpr auto MaxLen = Capacity - 1; // reserve NUL char

        assert(name.length() < MaxLen);
        std::copy_n(name.data(), std::min(name.length(), MaxLen), name_.data());
    }

    //Animal            ( Animal&&      animal  ) noexcept = default;
    //Animal            ( Animal const& animal  )          = default;
    //Animal& operator= ( Animal&&      animal  ) noexcept = default;
    //Animal& operator= ( Animal const& animal  )          = default;

    Name        name_;
    std::string description_;
    int         leg_{0};
    int         age_{0};
    double      maxSpeed_{0.0};
};
```

### Improving: `FixedString`

This just ***screams*** for a better `Name` type. How about, `FixedString`:

```
template <size_t N> struct FixedString {
    static_assert(N > 1); // require space for NUL char

    FixedString(std::string_view s) : data_{0} {
        if (s.length() >= N)
            throw std::length_error("FixedString");
        std::copy_n(s.data(), std::min(s.length(), N - 1), data());
    }

    std::string_view str() const { return { data(), size() }; }
    operator std::string_view() const { return str(); }

    auto data()   const { return data_.data(); }
    auto data()         { return data_.data(); }
    auto c_str()  const { return data_.data(); }
    auto c_str()        { return data_.data(); }

    auto begin() const { return data_.begin(); }
    auto end()   const { return data_.end();   }
    auto begin()       { return data_.begin(); }
    auto end()         { return data_.end();   }

    size_t size() const {
        auto terminator = std::memchr(data(), 0, data_.max_size());
        return terminator
            ? static_cast<char const*>(terminator) - data()
            : data_.max_size();
    };

    bool operator<(FixedString const& rhs)       const { return str() <  rhs.str(); }
    bool operator==(FixedString const& rhs)      const { return str() == rhs.str(); }
    bool operator!=(FixedString const& rhs)      const { return str() != rhs.str(); }
    // optimizations:
    bool operator<(std::string_view const& rhs)  const { return str() <  rhs.substr(0, N-1); }
    bool operator==(std::string_view const& rhs) const { return str() == rhs.substr(0, N-1); }
    bool operator!=(std::string_view const& rhs) const { return str() != rhs.substr(0, N-1); }

  private:
    std::array<char, N> data_;
};
```

Now you can simply

```
using Name = FixedString<50>;
```

And all your `Name`s will magically (and ***safely***) convert to and from string views.

```
using Name = FixedString<50>;

struct Animal {
    Animal(std::string_view name, std::string description,
           int leg = 0, int age = 0, double maxSpeed = 0) noexcept 
        : name_{name}, description_{std::move(description)},
          leg_{leg}, age_{age}, maxSpeed_{maxSpeed}
    { }

    Name        name_;
    std::string description_;
    int         leg_{0};
    int         age_{0};
    double      maxSpeed_{0.0};
};
```

### Everything Simplifies With The Right Abstraction

This is the most important lesson I think I learned in my programming career: choosing the right abstraction leads to simplicity. Here, we evaporate two messy helpers:

```
using Hasher         = std::hash<std::string_view>;
using KeysComparator = std::equal_to<Name>;
```

Boom. They do everything you had, but better.

### Now, The Missing Element

After simplifying the whole thing to [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/c1BoKS9QNnKHE8Kx) it should become pretty obvious that a `std::array<char, 50>` can ***never*** correctly contain names longer than 50 characters. Indeed, checking the insertions:

```
auto emplace_start = Now();

size_t duplicates = 0;
for (auto i = 0; i < elements_size; ++i) {
    auto [_, ok] = container.emplace_back(
        make_name(i), "bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla",
        4, i, i + 2);

    if (!ok) ++duplicates;
}
if (duplicates) {
    std::cerr << "Oops, " << duplicates << " duplicate keys not inserted\n";
}

auto emplace_end = Now();
```

Reveals that:

```
Oops, 999990 duplicate keys not inserted
Elapsed time emplace: 116.491ms iterate: 0.000145ms find: 0.000597ms, sum:45 , calculation for Animal_multi (boost multi_index)
```

> At least, now you replaced [Undefined
> Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) with
> constraint checks.

Of course, just increasing the name capacity fixes it: **[https://wandbox.org/permlink/6AamJfXe76nYALfR)**

```
using Name = FixedString<60>;
```

Prints:

```
Elapsed time emplace: 594.475ms iterate: 18.6076ms find: 0.003138ms, sum:499999500000 , calculation for Animal_multi (boost multi_index)
```

Alternatively you can throw on `Name` construction with an overly long name: **[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/5JYR5OrS5NItL6JX)**

```
FixedString(std::string_view s) : data_{0} {
    if (s.length() >= N)
        throw std::length_error("FixedString");
    std::copy_n(s.data(), std::min(s.length(), N - 1), data());
}
```

Which duly prints

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  FixedString
```

### [Full Listing](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Bf1MqC46h2fwBGb9)

This demo uses `FixedString<60>` to avoid the key errors:

```
#include <boost/multi_index_container.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/hashed_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/random_access_index.hpp>
#include <boost/multi_index/member.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

int constexpr elements_size{ 1'000'000 };

template <size_t N> struct FixedString {
    static_assert(N > 1); // require space for NUL char

    FixedString(std::string_view s) : data_{0} {
        if (s.length() >= N)
            throw std::length_error("FixedString");
        std::copy_n(s.data(), std::min(s.length(), N - 1), data());
    }

    std::string_view str() const { return { data(), size() }; }
    operator std::string_view() const { return str(); }

    auto data()   const { return data_.data(); }
    auto data()         { return data_.data(); }
    auto c_str()  const { return data_.data(); }
    auto c_str()        { return data_.data(); }

    auto begin() const { return data_.begin(); }
    auto end()   const { return data_.end();   }
    auto begin()       { return data_.begin(); }
    auto end()         { return data_.end();   }

    size_t size() const {
        auto terminator = std::memchr(data(), 0, data_.max_size());
        return terminator
            ? static_cast<char const*>(terminator) - data()
            : data_.max_size();
    };

    bool operator<(std::string_view const& rhs)  const { return str() <  rhs.substr(0, N-1); }
    bool operator==(std::string_view const& rhs) const { return str() == rhs.substr(0, N-1); }
    bool operator!=(std::string_view const& rhs) const { return str() != rhs.substr(0, N-1); }
    bool operator<(FixedString const& rhs)       const { return str() <  rhs.str(); }
    bool operator==(FixedString const& rhs)      const { return str() == rhs.str(); }
    bool operator!=(FixedString const& rhs)      const { return str() != rhs.str(); }

  private:
    std::array<char, N> data_;
};

using Name = FixedString<60>;

struct Animal {
    Animal(std::string_view name, std::string description,
           int leg = 0, int age = 0, double maxSpeed = 0) noexcept 
        : name_{name}, description_{std::move(description)},
          leg_{leg}, age_{age}, maxSpeed_{maxSpeed}
    { }

    Name        name_;
    std::string description_;
    int         leg_{0};
    int         age_{0};
    double      maxSpeed_{0.0};
};

using Hasher         = std::hash<std::string_view>;
using KeysComparator = std::equal_to<Name>;

using Clock     = std::chrono::steady_clock;
using Duration  = Clock::duration;
static auto Now = Clock::now;

void printStatistics(Duration emplace, Duration iterate, Duration find,
                     intmax_t const sum, std::string target)
{
    std::cout << "Elapsed time"
        << " emplace: " << (emplace/1.0ms) << "ms"
        << " iterate: " << (iterate/1.0ms) << "ms"
        << " find: " << (find/1.0ms) << "ms"
        << ", sum:" << sum
        << " , calculation for " << target
        << std::endl;
}

void test() {
    namespace bmi = boost::multi_index;
    using Animal_multi = bmi::multi_index_container<Animal,
      bmi::indexed_by<
        bmi::random_access<>,
        bmi::hashed_unique<
            bmi::tag<struct by_name>,
            bmi::member<Animal, Name, &Animal::name_>, Hasher, KeysComparator>
        >
    >;

    Animal_multi container;

    auto make_name = [](size_t id) {
        return "the really long name of some animal 12345678910_" + std::to_string(id);
    };

    auto emplace_start = Now();

    size_t duplicates = 0;
    for (auto i = 0; i < elements_size; ++i) {
        auto [_, ok] = container.emplace_back(
            make_name(i), "bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla",
            4, i, i + 2);

        if (!ok) ++duplicates;
    }
    if (duplicates) {
        std::cerr << "Oops, " << duplicates << " duplicate keys not inserted\n";
    }

    auto emplace_end = Now();

    intmax_t sum{ 0 };
    auto iterate_start = Now();
    for (auto const& e : container) {
        sum += e.age_;
    }
    auto iterate_end = Now();

    auto find_start = Now();
    {
        auto& name_idx = container.get<by_name>();
        auto last_key = make_name(elements_size - 1);
        if (name_idx.count(std::string_view(last_key)) == 0u) {
            std::cout << "WARN: Element has not been found." << std::endl;
        }
    }
    auto find_end = Now();

    printStatistics(
            emplace_end - emplace_start,
            iterate_end - iterate_start,
            find_end - find_start, sum,
            "Animal_multi (boost multi_index)");
}

int main() { test(); }
```